# how to change change the colour of dropdown in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

> i have a dropdown cboVendor i want to data in the dropdown to be in
>   red that is coming from `ELSE` part in the below `code`.but the problem
>   is that i am binding the data after the if-else.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboVendor" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
AutoPostBack="true"> <asp:ListItem Value="0">- Select Vendor -</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**c# code**

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == true) {
    cboVendor.DataSource = DAL.CertificationDA.GetFullAccreditedVendors(vendid);
    cboVendor.DataTextField = "SupplierName";
    cboVendor.DataValueField = "SupplierID";
} else {
    cboVendor.DataSource = Supplier.GetSuppliersForSite(UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser.GetValidLocations.wsm_Ref_Buildings.FindByBuildingId(cboBuilding.SelectedValue).SiteId);
    cboVendor.DataTextField = "SupplierName";
    cboVendor.DataValueField = "SupplierID";
}
cboVendor.DataBind();
```

Comment: DDL is rendered as `Select` in HTML so you can define a CSS class `vendor-list option { color: red }` and assign this class to `cboVendor` in else block using [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Write your else block 
cboVendor.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

Answer (score 0):

After binding data you can loop through the list items and you can set style or a class on those items like this

```
  if(Checkbox.Checked!=true){
       foreach(ListItem item in cboVendor.Items) {   
                 item.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red;");  
     }  
   }
```

Comment: actually both SP return different set of columns and i want the red in else part

Comment: You can add a check on it

Comment: You can add a check on it

Comment: pls also answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833622/change-background-color-of-dropdown-items-at-runtime-on-the-basis-of-flag-column

Comment: then accept this as answer, so that other peoples do not waste time to read this question

Comment: but the attribute value is loosing on postback

Comment: on post back you must be setting the list values again, you need to place this code in postback also

Comment: it will bind it again and rather than Changes value i.e from 1 to 2 it will show
 Select Vendor

Comment: do not bind it on post back only add the code that will change its color

Comment: without binding how will it know where to add the color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152625/discussion-between-ghulam-mohayudin-and-akhil-jain).